# typo3 v8 form check value to typoscript and yaml

Tags: forms, typo3-8.x

How can I at yaml e.g. to check a value?

I would like to check one value and thereby change the recipient or another.

Edit:
How can I check that in fluid, I realize. But not receiver or subject ... If I overlook something in the documentation that answers my question, I ask for the source.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/8.7/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#accessing-form-values

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I am dealing with yaml for the first time and also the documentation. However, there are no examples of how I can test the value. Therefore I miss the approach.